# C# duplicate extended class

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following classes:

```
 Class A {}

 Class B: A {}

 Class C: A {}
```

Now, I have 2 functions that fill either B or C with data. At the moment, 2 functions are required because one creates `New B()` and the other `New C()`.

I would like just one function that I can tell to use either B or C. I cannot just send a class and tell it to be filled, the called function needs to be able to create the classes on the fly.

Comment: Can you post some more code showing what you mean by "fill... with data?"

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I really don't understand what you want to do here - in addition to Michael's question, what do you mean by "I would like just one function that I can tell to use either B or C" - I've read this sentence five times over and I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: "*C# **duplicate** extended class*"? A bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a generic function with a `new` constraint on the type argument:

```
class FillerOfBsAndCs {
    A Fill<T>() where T : new(), A {
        // do the preparations...
        T res = new T();
        // fill res with data
        return res;
    }
}
```

You can now call this method like this:

```
FillerOfBsAndCs filler = new FillerOfBsAndCs();
A a1 = filler.Fill<B>();
A a2 = filler.Fill<C>();
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. This worked perfectly. I do have one other question. In the call filler.Fill<B>; Is there a way to replace 'T' with a local variable with a value of B? I would like to not have to pass the target class if possible.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss Passing in a local with a value of type `B` would be quite a bit more complex with solution based on generics, and it would be a lot slower, too. You can add an abstract method to `A` that creates a new instance of subclass (`B` returns `new B()`, `C` returns `new C()`, and so on), and use this method in a non-generic instance of `Fill` that takes an instance of `A` instead of type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a generic method

```
public T FillA<T>() where T : A, new()
{
    T newobj = new T();
    newobj.AProperty1 = valueForProperty1;
    newobj.AProperty2 = valueForProperty2;
    // etc.
    return newobj;
}
```